# How do you get a list of annual compound returns in numpy (or other library)?

Tags: python, numpy, finance

Start with $1000.

Invest it for 10 years, compounded annually.

Return table with annual returns, formatted thus $xxx,xxx.00

Solve without writing new implementation preferred.  Pythonic and concise with existing API should be possible, since this is one of the most common calculations on the planet (and probably other planets too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a range of financial tools in NumPy: see the [`np.lib.financial`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/routines.financial.html) module.

Here, I think you want [`fv`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fv.html). An example given in the documentation is the following:

> What is the future value after 10 years of saving $100 now, with an additional monthly savings of $100. Assume the interest rate is 5% (annually) compounded monthly?

```
>>> np.fv(0.05/12, 10*12, -100, -100)
15692.928894335748`
```

If any of the input values is an array, an array of values is returned. To compute the annual balances over 10 years (with the same assumptions as the example), you could write:

```
>>> np.fv(0.05/12, np.arange(0, 121, 10), -100, -100)
array([   100.        ,   1123.20552614,   2189.85294226,   3301.78664596,
         4460.92934179,   5669.28536592,   6928.94415193,   8242.08384379,
         9610.97506218,  11037.98483075,  12525.58066907])
```

This doesn't have the $xxx,xxx.00 formatting you've specified, but it should be straightforward to adjust NumPy's print options to get something satisfactory.

Comment: Interesting.  I had been working with np.fv function, but what i was missing was np.arange(0, 121, 10).  What exactly does that mean? By the way, formatting could also be done with currency_formatter = lambda x: 
print map(currency_formatter, list(future))

Comment: `np.arange(0, 121, 10)` just creates a NumPy array `[0, 10, 20, ..., 120]`, representing the number of months at which the future value in calculated.  I think you can also pass an array of values for the interest rate and monthly payments, etc. (as long as they're all the same length).

Comment: In that case, shouldn't it be np.arrange(0,121,12) resulting in   0,  12,  24,  36,  48,  60,  72,  84,  96, 108, 120]?

Comment: Ah yes - my mistake. `np.arrange(0,121,12)` would compute the balance annually.

Answer (score 1):

Since Numpy 1.20 (Jan 30, 2021) the [financial functions have been removed](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.20.0-notes.html#financial-functions-removed) and the docs now points to the [numpy-financial](https://pypi.org/project/numpy-financial/) library, which started as a raw copy of the original numpy functions.

This alternative library is hosted under the [numpy account on Github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy-financial) and [has not been updated since October 2019](https://pypi.org/project/numpy-financial/#history).

Personal suggestion: if you don't want to incorporate an additional dependency, just look at the code and use it, most functions are around 10 LoC without the docs. Beware of the license limitations though.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the compound interest is just:

```
def compound(present_value, rate, num_periods):
  return present_value * (1 + rate) ** num_periods
```

You can pass numpy arrays if you want, e.g. the yearly balance after 10 years with an annual interest rate of 3% starting with $1000:

```
>>> compound(1000.0, rate=0.03, num_periods=np.arange(11))
array([1000.        , 1030.        , 1060.9       , 1092.727     ,
       1125.50881   , 1159.2740743 , 1194.05229653, 1229.87386542,
       1266.77008139, 1304.77318383, 1343.91637934])
```